# in javascript if Object A has a property is another object B ,how can i get A in B

Tags: javascript

```
var A = {
    cc: 'opps',
    B: {
        dd: 'dd',
        getC: function () {
            return this.cc
        }
    }
}
```

how can i get cc ?? return A.cc in method getC or function () {return this.cc}.bind(this) or other way?

Comment: It might need a clearer example, but couldn't you just do A.cc?

Answer (score 2):

If it's really a one-off object like that, just use `A.cc`:

```
var A = {
    cc: 'opps',
    B: {
        dd: 'dd',
        getC: function () {
            return A.cc;
        }
    }
};
```

If you have a constructor or builder producing these, then you'd have to do something in the constructor. It's hard to help you with that without an example, but for instance:

```
// Constructor, used via new, e.g.: new Thingy()
function Thingy() {
    var t = this;
    t.cc = 'opps';
    t.B = {
        dd: 'dd',
        getC: function () {
            return t.cc;
        }
    };
}

// Builder, used without new, e.g.: createThingy()
function createThingy() {
    var A = {
        cc: 'opps',
        B: {
            dd: 'dd',
            getC: function () {
                return A.cc;
            }
        }
    };
    return A;
}
```